# Whats the best option for creating a multi-targeted phone platform media server

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone

I'm working on a new project where we are hoping to create an applicaiton that streams media to iOS, Android and Windows phone. We like a cloud based solution so that we can scale easily if traffic picks up and we'd like to architect things so that as much business logic and applicaiton logic as possible is behind the shared services. We'd prefer a .Net based solution but are open to whatever works best. I've tried googling this but I'm not finding a lot out there on this.

Comment: If the only need is to stream media, with nothing that custom, there might be some pre-baked solutions to what you need. Other wise, take a look at Google App Engine, Amazon S3, Heroku, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a .NET based approach take a look at [Azure mobile services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/resources/). It doesn't support push notification for Andriod, but it doesn't look like you actually need that.